No network access after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04
I have a dedicated server on ovh-cloud. I upgraded it to 24.04 and since then it can't access any network:
$ nslookup security.ubuntu.com
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
;; no servers could be reached

$ wget https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/noble-infra-security/InRelease
--2024-09-16 12:03:44--  https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/noble-infra-security/InRelease
Resolving esm.ubuntu.com (esm.ubuntu.com)... 
failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘esm.ubuntu.com’


This may be a duplicate of Internet is not working after upgrading to ubuntu 24.04
You can temporarily edit /etc/resolv.conf
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

and replace all content with
nameserver 9.9.9.9

Then your connection should work again.
After this
sudo apt install systemd-resolved

